# $ionicPlatform causing crash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

As soon as I add the dependency to the controller and use it in the controller and try to click a link to the Profile view, it stays on the same view. On top of that, I am not getting any errors in the error console.

Controller:
    .

```
controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform) {

   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        window.screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
        console.log("it triggered");
    })

})
```

When I refresh the direct link to the Profile view to force the page to load, I DO NOT see the "it triggered" message in the console.

This is probably a syntax issue or something small...thanks in advance:)

Comment: Can you share a https://plnkr.co/ link with your code?

Comment: I created a blank app so no mess....here is the Github: https://github.com/MehdiN0101/CGapp-Blank-Test.git

Comment: It's giving me this error that window.screen.lockOrientation is not a function. https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/issues/68

Comment: Any solutions? maybe should i remove and reinstall the plugin...BTW I'm testing on my iPhone device